# How i should do it correctly? Unity Photon

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

When I try to pick up the lamp, it appears in the player's hands who picked it up, but for other players, it just spawns at a point, and does not bind to the player.

Also i tried to comment first 2 lines of code in AddLamp method, and now there is 2 lamps on the map, so weird. Can you help me, please?

```
private﻿ void Update()
{
    if(!photonView.IsMine && PhotonNetwork.IsConnected)
        return;
    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(PICKUP) && _inRange && _item != null) 
        photonView.RPC("TakeItem",  RpcTarget.All);
}

[PunRPC]
private void TakeItem()
{
    if (!ItIsObject())
        return;
     if (_item.CompareTag(_itemTags[3]))
    {
        if(_itemInventoryScript.haveMainItem)
            return;
        //photonView.RPC("AddLamp", RpcTarget.All);
        _itemInventoryScript.AddLamp();
    }

    
    _audioSource.PlayOneShot(_pickUpSound);
    _triggerEnters--;
    Destroy(_item);
}
[ANOTHER SCRIPT]

public void AddLamp()
{
    if(!photonView.IsMine && PhotonNetwork.IsConnected)
        return;
    
    haveMainItem = true;
    
    GameObject lamp = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(HANDITEMSPATH + _lampPrefab.name, _itemsPosition.position, Quaternion.identity);
    lamp.transform.parent = _itemsPosition;
    lamp.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0.03f, 0.15f);
    lamp.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 30);
}
```

If do simple Instantiate(without PhotonNetwork) i can't get access to object, because IsMine always false

Comment: You could add a component to sync the transform of the lamp across the network.  It looks like you are relying on setting the parent of the lamp to the player who spawned it.  What about those other clients?  They see the object get spawned via PhotonNetwork.Instantiate, but do nothing with it.  For transform sync via parenting to work, you would have to parent the lamp to that players clone on each other connected client.  I've done something in the past using an RPC call to parent the object across all clients, but that was for a small number of well defined objects.